# Как сложить все числа выведенные циклом for?

Tags: python, циклы, for

Есть некий цикл for, который расчитывает цену лимитных ордеров, который выводит следующее:

```
19030.95
18973.8
18878.55
18745.2
18573.75
18364.2
18116.55
17830.8
17506.95
17145.0
```

Вопрос как получить сумму всех этих чисел. Ниже сам цикл:

````
import math
MAX_ORDERS = 10
base_order_price = 19050.00 #текущая цена монеты
for i in range(MAX_ORDERS):
    setka = base_order_price - base_order_price * (MAX_ORDERS ** math.log(i + 1, MAX_ORDERS) * (i + 1)) / 100 / MAX_ORDERS
    print(setka)```
````

Answer (score 1):

используйте функцию `sum` - она складывает все значения в списке:

```
res = sum(base_order_price - base_order_price * (MAX_ORDERS ** math.log(i + 1, MAX_ORDERS) * (i + 1)) / 100 / MAX_ORDERS for i in range(MAX_ORDERS))
```

ну или по старинке с накоплением переменной:

```
res = 0
for i in range(MAX_ORDERS):
    setka = base_order_price - base_order_price * (MAX_ORDERS ** math.log(i + 1, MAX_ORDERS) * (i + 1)) / 100 / MAX_ORDERS
    res += setka
```